# Can't start the Android emulator – 'WHPX: Unexpected VP exit code 5'

Tags: windows, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, hypervisor

I can't start the Android emulator.
It always exits with the error: `WHPX: Unexpected VP exit code 5`.

I used Android Studio 3.6.2 and the latest Android Virtual Device (AVD).
And I installed the **Windows Hypervisor Platform**, and enabled Virtual Technology in the BIOS.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Im my case (Windows 10 + Intellij IDE + Pixel 2 + API 29), enabling HyperV in Windows feature in addition to Hypervisor feature helped me to run AVD without any error.
[image]

Hope to be useful for you too :).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cold boot option to start emulator. It works fine for me. I have not found any other solution.